# Pandas Python: Count occurrence of value based on date and user column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this:

| yy_mm_dd | userid | metrics | value | metric_benchmark | risk_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-03-17 | Tom | run | 3 | 3 | no risk |
| 01-03-18 | Tom | run | 4 | 3 | no risk |
| 01-03-17 | Tom | walk | 11 | 11 | no risk |
| 01-05-18 | Tom | walk | 9 | 11 | at risk |
| 01-05-19 | Tom | walk | 8 | 11 | at risk |
| 01-05-17 | Sue | run | 2 | 3 | at risk |
| 01-05-17 | Sue | run | 5 | 3 | no risk |

I want to count how many times a user is **at risk** or **no risk** 2 or more days in a row.

This is the code that I wrote, but it's not taking into account the order of the date column.

```
final = df.groupby(['userid','metrics','risk_level'])[['risk_level']].count()
final
```

Expected Outcome:

| userid | metrics | risk_level | days_risk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | run | no risk | 2 days |
| Tom | walk | no risk | 1 day |
| Tom | walk | at risk | 2 days |
| Sue | run | at risk | 1 day |
| Sue | run | no risk | 1 day |

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: If your header is correct, none of your lines have 2 days in a row.  The first two lines are a year apart.  Is that actually `"yy-mm-dd"`?

Comment: oh I apologize for this. I will edit the data for it to be a day wise data

Comment: oh yes, I will add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) to get the difference on successive days and count the maximum number of consecutive days:

```
df['yy_mm_dd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yy_mm_dd'], format='%y-%m-%d')

group = ['userid', 'metrics', 'risk_level']

out = (df.groupby(group, sort=False, as_index=False)['yy_mm_dd']
         .apply(lambda s: s.groupby(s.diff().gt('1d').cumsum()).size().max())
         .rename(columns={'yy_mm_dd': 'days_risk'})
      )
```

*NB. this assumes that the dates are originally sorted.*

Output:

```
  userid metrics risk_level  days_risk
0    Tom     run    no risk          2
1    Tom    walk    no risk          1
2    Tom    walk    at risk          2
3    Sue     run    at risk          1
4    Sue     run    no risk          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this as a basis.  I convert your date column to real dates, then extract only the "at risk" rows, then compute the difference between each consecutive row, then count the number of rows for each user where the delta is 1 day.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['yy_mm_dd','userid','metrics','value','metric_benchmark','risk_level']
data = [
    ['01-03-17','Tom','run',3,3,'no risk'],
    ['01-03-18','Tom','run',4,3,'no risk'],
    ['01-03-17','Tom','walk',11,11,'no risk'],
    ['01-05-18','Tom','walk',9,11,'at risk'],
    ['01-05-19','Tom','walk',8,11,'at risk'],
    ['01-05-17','Sue','run',2,3,'at risk'],
    ['01-05-17','Sue','run',5,3,'no risk']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
# Convert the date column to dates.
df['yy_mm_dd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yy_mm_dd'], yearfirst=True)
# Pull only the "at risk" columns.
df = df[df['risk_level'] == 'at risk']
# Compute the date difference from the previous row.
df['delta'] = df['yy_mm_dd'].diff()
print(df)

print(df[df['delta'] == '1 day'].groupby('userid').count())
```

Output:

```
    yy_mm_dd userid metrics  value  metric_benchmark risk_level   delta
3 2001-05-18    Tom    walk      9                11    at risk     NaT
4 2001-05-19    Tom    walk      8                11    at risk  1 days
5 2001-05-17    Sue     run      2                 3    at risk -2 days
        yy_mm_dd  metrics  value  metric_benchmark  risk_level  delta
userid                                                               
Tom            1        1      1                 1           1      1
```